# When the idea starts, it gives the error "Failed to load module 'canberra-gtk-module'". How should I fix it?

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

I downloaded the Linux version of idea and unzip it to my /opt/idea-IU-181.5540.7 directory (my system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).
When I executed./idea.sh on bin, there was an error in the terminal "Failed to load module'canberra-gtk-module'":

```
slf@slf-pc:/opt/idea-IU-181.5540.7/bin$ ./idea.sh 
Gtk-Message: 17:45:12.518: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
slf@slf-pc:/opt/idea-IU-181.5540.7/bin$
```

But idea startup is no problem at the moment. Should I fix this error? If it needs to be repaired, how should I repair it?

Comment: You can ignore this harmless warning.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can ignore that message as it doesn't crashes the IDE in any form. If you want to get rid of the message, then run the below command:

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk-module
```

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/MajeurAndroid/Adb-Remote-Screen/issues/14)

After I ran the above command, this error disappeared during any Jetbrains IDE launch.

Answer (score 3):

For a CentOS 7 (7.6) system, I used:

```
sudo yum install libcanberra-gtk2
```

and the problem went away.  CentOS 7.6 apparently uses gtk3, but the IntelliJ products are looking for the gtk2 modules.